# Add specific item from ArrayList into LinkedList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with lots of objects. I want to be able to add any objects into a choice of 3 different `LinkedLists`. A user input will select which item to add to which LinkedList by typing the index they wish to be added. This is the kind of thing i'm after, but i just can't get it to work:

```
public void addToRepository(int indx, int r) {
    if (r == 1){ //checks to see if chosen repository 1
        for (int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            i = indx;
        } // ignore this it was just me playing around to see if i'd be able to get the index this way..
        repo1.add(itemList.get(indx)); //adds item from "itemList" with the index that
                                         the user input has given
    //other if statements   
    }                                   
}
```

I'm not sure this is the correct idea but it gives error "Item cannot be converted to String". If not, how can i go about doing this?

Comment: Your for loop looks useless. Why is it there? Also what are the types of variables you are storing in `itemList` and `repo1`?

Comment: Please show us how you define `repo1` and `itemList`.  Also, your `for` loop looks totally bogus.

Comment: @AniketThakur i was just playing with it, i thought i'd be able to look and with the loop get the index to then add to the linked list. `itemList` stores Items `ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();`, here's a print of  `itemList` `Item{itemNo=12401, description=15th century table, price=1200.0}`

Comment: I'm with them on the for loop. It looks like repo1 contains strings, based on the compiler complaint. If that's the case, then Item needs to override (implement?) toString() to allow it to be converted.

Comment: Either that or repo1 needs to contain Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

and you are trying to do -

```
repo1.add(itemList.get(indx));
```

As per the Exception you are getting it looks like `repo1` has String data. You can do one of the following things -

1. Use `repo1.add(itemList.get(indx).toString());` OR
2. Change `repo1` generics to include `Item` data instead of `String`

Comment: Note that he has to implement or override `Item.toString()` in order for the first solution to work.

Comment: Yup don't miss overriding `toString()` method or else the implementation from `Object` will be used and you will get something like class name @ hashcode which may not make any sense to the user.

Comment: @RonThompson `Item` already has a `toString`. So what's the difference if i change the `LinkedLists` to include `item` instead?

Comment: If item already has toString() that solution would be faster, but changing repo to contain Items is probably the smarter move.

Comment: Just declare it as `LinkedList<Item> repo1 = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Note that that may break other sections of your code that currently depend on repo containing `String`. Up to you.

Comment: Note above syntax will work only with Java 7. If using 6 or below use `LinkedList<Item> repo1 = new LinkedList<Item>();`

Comment: Either way at some point you'll end up using ` Item.toString()`

Comment: `if (Java6) upgrade to Java7 else be happy`